# How to get HTML representation of a child element in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Assuming my HTML is:

```
<html><body><span>This is my text</span></body></html>
```

How do I get a string representation of what's contained inside , i.e:

```
<span>This is my text</span>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the html representation of an element just use the built in `str` function:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<html><body><span>This is my text</span></body></html>")
span = soup.find('span')
str(span) # Outputs '<span>This is my text</span>'
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup works with unicode. So, it's better to use `unicode` function instead of `str`. Unicode will work fine with non-roman characters.